# perl storing text file into variable by splitting content

Tags: perl, hash

I am new to perl scripting and have to maintain someone's script. There is a subroutine to parse a config file content (with standard format of three columns).

- What is line `$info{$name}{$b}{address}=$address` used for?
- Is it a hash?
- How do I access the parsed content in the main code?

For example, `foreach name`, get the `son's name` and `address`.

```
my $msg="";
my @names;
my %info=parseCfg($file);

foreach $name (@names) {
   $msg="-I-: Working on $name\n";
   $a=$info{}{}{};

sub parseCfg {
    my $file=$_[0];
    if (-e $file) {
        open (F,"<$file") or die "Fail to open $file\n";
        $msg="-I-: Reading from config file: $file\n";
        print $msg; print LOG $msg;
        my %seen;
        while (<F>) {
            my ($name,$b,$address)=@fields;
            push (@names,$name);
            
            $info{$name}{$b}{address}=$address;
        }
        close F;
    } else {
        die "-E-: Missing config file $file\n";
    }
    return %info;
}
```

Example of config file:

Format: Name son's_name address

```
Adam aaa xxx
Billy bbb yyy
Cindy ccc sss
```

Comment: Always add `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: yea i did use. Just not pasting whole code here

Comment: I think this is false as far as you don't declare variables with `my`

Comment: i did actually, just not pasting whole code.

Comment: `foreach $name (@names)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're recommanded to use `use strict; use warnings;`, so most of the errors (syntax & compilation) can be avoided and have a clean code.

I just ran your code, and its still having the compilation errors. Suggesting you to paste compiled running code in SO, it would help community to answer your question in faster way.

I have re-written your code and its giving the result as you mentioned - Son Name and Address. This would work only if you have unique `Name's` in your input file. If two person is having same name with different Son and Addresses this logic needs to be altered.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; 
use warnings;

my $file = "/path/to/file/file.txt";
my %info = parseCfg($file);

foreach my $name (keys %info){
    print "-I-: Working on $name\n";
    print "SON: $info{$name}{'SON'}\n";
    print "ADDRESS: $info{$name}{'ADDRESS'}\n";
}

sub parseCfg {
    my $file = shift;
    
    my %data;
    return if !(-e $file);
    
    open(my $fh, "<", $file) or die "Can't open < $file: $!";
    my $msg = "-I-: Reading from config file: $file\n";
    print $msg; #print LOG $msg;
    my %seen;
    while (<$fh>) {
        my @fields = split(" ", $_);
        my ($name, $b, $address) = @fields;
        $data{$name}{'SON'} = $b;
        $data{$name}{'ADDRESS'} = $address;
    }
    close $fh;
    return %data;
}
```

Result:

```
-I-: Reading from config file: /path/to/file/file.txt
-I-: Working on Adam
SON: aaa
ADDRESS: xxx
-I-: Working on Billy
SON: bbb
ADDRESS: yyy
-I-: Working on Cindy
SON: ccc
ADDRESS: sss
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and the rewritten code. I will try out the code. What if the name column in the input file is not unique?

Comment: _What if the name column in the input file is not unique_: Hash is storing the values based on the keys. Here in this case `name` is our key, so it will override the previous values which is been stored in the hash. So it should be unique. Another alternative is make a key combination with name + son's name.

Comment: What if neither any column in the input file is unique? Is hash still a proper way to store? Is there any other way parse the 3 category from the input file?

Comment: @peace I have already mentioned that in previous comment. FYI. _Another alternative is make a key combination with name + son's name_